# Oreo 8.1: Day of the week not displaying in notification drawer

Tags: notifications, 8.1-oreo, date-and-time, app-drawer

I'm running Android Oreo 8.1. How do I have the day off the week show up next to the date in the notification drawer drop-down?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Date in Status Bar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wagwan.datestatusbarlite). It will display the day of the week in short format above the date. However, the month and year are not shown (I have not seen them when testing). When you expand the status bar, the day of the week, date, month and year are all shown.
Here are how the date is displayed:

a. When the status bar is not expanded

[image: IMG:]

b. When the status bar is expanded

[image: IMG:]